# Is there a way to parse this html form?

Tags: python, html, json

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import lxml
 import urllib.request

 payload = {'userName': 'UN', 'password': 'PW'}
 r = requests.post("http://helpdesk/", data=payload).text
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html5lib')

 print(soup)
```

I get this output after running the above code:

[image]

I would like to grab the information from there in the below format so I can keep reusing it instead of hard coding the value

Starters name : value
Job Title: value

How do I go about achieving this?

Thank you

Comment: post html contents.

Comment: do you mean the one I sent as the screen shot?

Comment: Strip whitespace?